# Database is not reflecting in sh.status()

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.2

I have a 2 shard (s1 and s0 )servers with repl set. s1 has 2 dbs (db-A and db-B) and one of the db is sharded (db-B).

When i do sh.status() from mongos only (db-B) is displayed. I am wondering what i need to do for identifying of db-A by mongos.

Answer (score 1):

```
db.getSiblingDB.databases.find()
```

Those databases what have "partitioned":false are not sharded and you can see from "primary":xxx key which shard those are located.

> How to access a DB for which sharding is not enabled and none of its collections are sharded?

As you normally access them, but of course thru mongos.. Like you access all other collections in the different DB's.  There is nothing special access method when collection is sharded or not, just remember always use mongoS and not read/write collection directly on one shard. Just use `use yourDBName` and then `show collections` or `db.collection.find()`